# iOS Outlook Add-in not respecting Set-Cookies header for external sites in Dialog

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've an Outlook web add-in that uses the Office.js Dialog API to open a dialog that navigates to an external (i.e. not on my add-in domain) authentication landing page. When that page is loaded in the dialog it passes back a Set-Cookie header with a return URL value set to a page in my add-in, then redirects to a different external site to perform SAML authentication (whoever the user has configured as their SAML provider). When login completes the user is navigated to a completion page on the authentication landing domain, which is then expected to read the cookie that was initially set and redirect back to the add-in using the URL in the cookie.

This works fine on desktop platforms however when using the add-in through the Outlook IOS app I'm seeing that the **Set-Cookies** header does not seem to work as when the flow reaches the completion page there are no cookies present.

e.g. (using placeholder URLs), add-in function file loaded from https://my-addin.com/home

- Add-in launches dialog at https://my-addin.com/redirect (same domain as add-in loaded from).
- That page redirects to https://auth-helper.com/auth?returnUrl=https://my-addin.com/finalize. Set-Cookie header is passed back from server with a value ReturnURL=https://my-addin.com/finalize
- Redirects to configured SAML login page https://authenticate/login, passing return url to SAML provider as https://auth-helper.com/auth/completion.
- When user logs in successfully they are redirected to https://auth-helper.com/completion.
  Completion page tries to read value of ReturnURL from cookie to navigate back to add-in but there is no ReturnURL present in cookies on iOS.

  - Can also see from proxy tool monitoring requests that expected cookie is not present on requests to auth-helper after it should have been set.

From testing it looks like Set-Cookie header works for pages in the add-in domain when they are loaded in the dialog i.e. if I pass back Set-Cookie on the page I open dialog with and then navigate to another page on my add-in domain the cookie will have been set as expected and be readable from the second page. But for pages outside of the add-in domain it seems to be failing to set the cookie for later use.

```
Set-Cookie: ReturnURL=https://my-addin.com/finalize;Version=1;Path=/auth;Domain=auth-helper;Max-Age=86400;HttpOnly;Secure;SameSite=None
```

- Example header returned that does not appear to be working on iOS add-in dialog.

Can anyone think of any workarounds, causes or solutions here?

- I cannot modify the behaviour of pages outside of my add-in.
- The page I redirect to has X-Frame-Options set to sameorigin so I cannot load it in a hidden iFrame outside of the dialog.
- This flow works on desktop Safari, Chrome, IE, Windows Outlook client, Mac Outlook client and was previously seen to work on iOS back in September 2019 indicating a change on the platform itself.
- On the iOS device under Safari settings 'Prevent Cross-Site Tracking' and 'Block All Cookies' settings are both off.

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?
Is it possible for you to share stripped down version of your Add-in so that we can try to repro the issue at our end?

Comment: Outlook App is 4.34.1. iOS 12.4.1.

I cannot provide a stripped down version of the add-in for this as I don't have any publicly accessible external sites I could make available for your use unfortunately.

The add-in code should open a dialog with Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync, pointing to a dialog page. Dialog page should then redirect to a site on a different domain that passes back Set-Cookies header. Then go to another page on that same external domain and try to access the cookie that should have been set.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS device was upgraded from OS 12.4.1 to 13.4.1 and this problem no longer occurs. So we're going to have to recommend users upgrade iOS as we haven't found any other way around this.